# In a C3line chart, I would like to make the solid line appear dashed between selected data points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I want to make line appear dashed between two points in the chart.Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Include the C3.js and D3.js libraries -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.20/c3.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.20/c3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>

  <script>
    // Sample data for the line chart
    var data = {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250], // Sample line data (data1)
      ],
      regions: {
        data1: [{start: 2, end: 4, style: 'dashed'}],//
      },
    };

    // Chart configuration
    var chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#chart',
      data: data,
      axis: {
        x: {
        },
        y: {
        },
      },
      point:{
        show:false
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

With the above, I was able to make a dashed region between selected intervals but I was not able to customize the spacing of dashed lines.

Comment: Afraid you're out of luck on that one - rather than do something like have different path elements with different css styling for this, c3 hardwires the dashing within the one path by making them all individually calculated segments of the path :( - https://github.com/c3js/c3/blob/41b140ada9d624a6a0537978e4a56d8c7956eb94/src/shape.line.ts#L303